# what's System.UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have this code that allows a screenshot of my windows phone :

```
private void TakeScreenShot()
{

     // Take a screenshot 
     var screenshot = new WriteableBitmap(this, null);
     var screenshotname = String.Format("Screenshooter_{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
     using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
           screenshot.SaveJpeg(ms, 480, 800, 0, 85);
           ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

           var library = new MediaLibrary();
           var pic = library.SavePicture(screenshotname, ms);
     }    
     MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Screenshot saved as ", screenshotname));
}
```

But I have an exeption (System.UnauthorizedAccessException) this instruction :

```
var pic = library.SavePicture(screenshotname, ms);
```

How to throw the exception? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`UnauthorizedAccessException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx) typically means you have a security issue or access issue because of `I/O` in `MediaLibrary`.

Comment: You don't have authority to write to `MediaLibrary`.

Comment: ok I've add the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO and it works fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error stated - **You don't have authority to write to `MediaLibrary`.**

You need to add permission from capabilities tab.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error. Source: msdn
It seems that you do not have access to your media library